# Amplification needed to power Helmholtz coils

Tags: power-amplifier, function-generator, voltage-amplification

I'm having trouble generating magnetic flux between [these coils](https://www.phywe.com/physics/modern-physics/quantum-physics/helmholtz-coils-one-pair_18148_20154/) that are hooked up to a [function generator](https://www.testequipmentdepot.com/instek-mfg-2120ma-20-mhz-single-channel-arbitrary-function-generator-pulse-modulation-amp.html). An oscilloscope is also used to monitor the waveform.

The issue that I'm having is that I cannot generate enough power to get the desired magnetic field. However, since my background does not lie in neither physics nor electronics, I'm having trouble figuring out how to amplify power. I have tried using a PAM8610 Mini 10W+10W Stereo Audio Power Amplifier, but this did not work either. I feel a bit out of my depth, and this project was kind of thrown on me, so any help at all would be appreciated. This stuff is very much new to me.

Comment: It is non-trivial to drive a Helmholtz coil because of both the power and their inductance. Ideally a constant current driver is needed. There are available off-the-shelf commercial Helmholtz Coil Drivers to solve this very issue. It will depend upon your particular requirements - ask the vendor of the coils?

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, I thought of that route, too and did confirm with a vendor that a commercial option would work but my concern is cost and time to ship/arrive as this is something that I need to resolve as soon as possible. Thank you, though!

Comment: from an engineer's point of view, if time-to-readiness is the critical thing, and you don't have the experience yet yourself (as you recognize yourself): Buy the commercial thing.

Comment: What frequency of stimulus are your trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you, honestly I agree and hopefully can convince others the same!

Comment: @Andyaka 50 Hz for now.